# Menu mudando o conteúdo da página

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-font-face

Fala galera, estou produzindo um Site e fiz um Menu HTML + CSS, o único problema é que o Menu está mudando o posicionamento das coisas que estão a baixo dele, exemplo:
se existe o menu e abaixo existe um < p> Teste < /p> ao rolar as opções do menu, ele altera o posicionamento do < p>, tem como deixar o menu sobre escrever os itens que estão abaixo dele?
por exemplo, existe o menu e abaixo existe o  < h1 > TITULO < /h1>, quando selecionar algum item com submenu o mesmo sobre escreva o < h1>
Este é o meu código do css:

```css
#nav{
    float: left;
    margin: 100px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    margin-left: 340px;
}

#nav ul {

    font: 16px arial, tahoma, verdana;

    list-style: none;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

}

 

#nav ul li {

    float: left;

   position: relative;

    display: block;

}

 

#nav ul li a {

    color: #555;

    background: #FFF;

    text-decoration: none;

    margin: 0 1px;

    padding: 15px 20px;

    border-top: 1px solid #555;

    display: block;

}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #066;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#nav li:hover a {

    background: #333;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #222;
}
#textos{
    height: 500px;
}s
```

Comment: Só com CSS não tem como analisar. Mas só adiantando, um submenu deve ter `position: absolute` para não afetar os outros elementos.

Comment: Complete a sua pergunta colocando o HTML também para que possam te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia @ThinKing.

Estou tentando entender o que realmente você quer.

Você tem um menu e embaixo conteúdo, quando você abre os submenus ele está empurrando o conteúdo correto?

Você precisa trabalhar com submenu com position absolute.
Montei um exemplo, espero ter ajudado.

Segue o link abaixo.

https://codepen.io/danilorb/pen/opGJGa

Comment: Caraca, deu para entender muito bem...

Comment: Muito obrigado, era o que eu realmente queria entender...

Comment: O que precisar estamos aqui. =)